# I need a div to align at the bottom of the page. The div contains 5 other divs inside of it

Tags: html, css, alignment, bulma

**The HTML is written with Bulma**

I have five divs inside of the main div and I want all of them to be at the very bottom

```
<div class="columns is-mobile" class="forecastContainer">
            <div class="column is-1 blank">
                <!--Blank Space-->
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2" id="dayTwo">
                <h1>Day</h1>
                <p>Icon</p>
                <p>High</p>
                <p>Humid</p>
                <p>Wind</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2" id="dayThree">
                <h1>Day</h1>
                <p>Icon</p>
                <p>High</p>
                <p>Humid</p>
                <p>Wind</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2" id="dayFour">
                <h1>Day</h1>
                <p>Icon</p>
                <p>High</p>
                <p>Humid</p>
                <p>Wind</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2" id="dayFive">
                <h1>Day</h1>
                <p>Icon</p>
                <p>High</p>
                <p>Humid</p>
                <p>Wind</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2" id="daySix">
                <h1>Day</h1>
                <p>Icon</p>
                <p>High</p>
                <p>Humid</p>
                <p>Wind</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-1">
                <!--Blank Space-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS for said Div(s)**

I'm not sure if the positioning is working so I haven't included it.

```
#dayTwo, #dayThree, #dayFour, #dayFive, #daySix {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.00rem;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 450px;
}

#daySix {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

**I would like the divs to always stay at the bottom even if the user scrolls.**

Answer (score 0):

Try position fixed.

```
      #dayTwo, #dayThree, #dayFour, #dayFive, #daySix 
      {
         position: fixed;
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

give the main div these properties:

```
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
```

not sure how you want the columns to look but if you want them to be on the same line use instead:

```
display: inline-flex;
```